# CSS animation to move divs upwords

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to use CSS animation to move these divs upwards as shown in the GIF attached below.

All the divs move upwards at the same speed.

I tried the marquee tag but from what I heard, it's depreciated or will be depreciated soon. So I can't use it.

I have never done CSS animation. So would really appreciate your help.

Each column has 6 items. When the entire 6 items are finished, it starts from item 1 again. Elements that overflow remain hidden, till all other items are displayed and then appear from the bottom again after the 6th element.

[image]

[image: Video demo here]

```css
.gridcontainer{
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  

}

.grid{
display:grid;
justify-items: center
}


    .grid--1x3{
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     justify-items: "center"
    }
    
    .flexcolumn {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='grid grid--1x3'>

<div class='flexcolumn'>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

</div>
<div class='flexcolumn'>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

</div>

<div class='flexcolumn'>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
<span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The gif has a sort of jerkiness when it restarts - am I right that you would like a continuous flow of these elements going upwards?

Comment: Your question says that each column has 10 items but your code shows only 6. Which is correct?

Comment: Let assume 6. Yes, continuous flow of these elements going upwards.

Comment: Don't have time to strip the code for you. But check this article: https://ryanmulligan.dev/blog/css-marquee/ and this demo: https://codepen.io/hexagoncircle/full/wvmjomb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of achieving a continuous movement is to have two copies of everything within a single container.

Then the container is translated upwards but just half of its height - the second copy will be overwritten by the first at the end of the animation so things look continuous.

This snippet assumes that the outer container may be of a different (smaller) height (as shown in the gif - not all the messages show at once) - so there is an outer container with overflow hidden and an inner container which is what is translated upwards.

```html
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.gridcontainer {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
  rposition: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2vw;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: fit-content;
}

.grid--1x3 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.flexcolumn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
  <div class='grid grid--1x3'>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>
    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='grid grid--1x3'>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>
    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

    <div class='flexcolumn'>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
      <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@keyframes move {
   from { bottom: 0   }
   to   { bottom: 200px }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

You can use keyframes to add animations

Answer (score 0):

First, your grid should be shorter in length than the elements it contains to create an overflow.
Then you can shift the columns that are in the grid with the `transform: translateY()` propery.

However you want to create an animation I see in your example, so you will have to define a [keyframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) to create an animation.

I have taken the following steps in the example below:

1. Created a variable containing the height of the grid. I did this
   because we need this exact value in 2 different places.
2. Set the height of the grid based on the variable.
3. Set overflow to hidden, so that the "overflow" is not visible.
4. Created a keyframe called slide. In this keyframe you see 2 steps:
   **0%**: with the value transform: translateY(0). This indicates the
   normal position, so nothing happens yet.
   **100%**: This is the end of
   the animation. With -100% I indicate that I want the last element at
   the beginning of the grid.
   However, we run into a problem: in your example I see that you want the last element to stop at the bottom
   of the grid. To achieve this we have to stop the animation a little
   earlier. Using a calc() function where we add the height of the grid
   to the -100%, we arrive at the bottom of the grid.
5. The animation applied to the columns for a time of 10s, with the
   setting infinitate so that the animation keeps repeating

```css
:root {
  /*   step 1 */
  --height: 250px;
}
.gridcontainer{
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;

}

.grid{
display:grid;
justify-items: center;
background-color: red;
/*   step 2 */
height: var(--height);
/*   step 3 */
overflow: hidden;
}


    .grid--1x3{
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     justify-items: "center"
    }
    
    .flexcolumn {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /*   step 5 */
    animation: slide 5s infinite;
    }

/*   step 4 */
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% + var(--height)));
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class='grid grid--1x3'>

<div class="flexcolumn">
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>
</div>
    
<div class="flexcolumn">
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>
</div>
    
<div class="flexcolumn">
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element A</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element B</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element C</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element D</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element E</span>
  <span class='gridcontainer'>Element F</span>
</div>
    
    


</div>
```